# Apply encryption to existing S3 objects without impacting storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-glacier

I am trying to encrypt an existing s3 bucket. When I do this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://test/ s3://test/ --recursive --sse
```

it is encrypting all the files in the bucket by re-copying the objects. My issue here is that I have objects in the bucket in Standard, Standard-IA and Glacier storage classes. So, when I run the above copy command the objects in Standard-IA storage are converted to standard storage. (I haven't tested what happens to objects in glacier yet - probably it won't even allow me to copy.)

Is there any way where we can restore the storage type of an object and just enable encryption for an existing bucket?

Comment: AWS will always store object in Standard storage unless you specify the other storage class explicitly.  In addition, watch our Glacier retrieval cost traps. Use glacier if you are pretty sure there is no need to retrieve the data in mid and long term.  Otherwise Standard_IA is sufficient for short-mid term usage.

Comment: I am using three different types of storage on the objects in the same bucket. object placed in the bucket is standard ,> 30 days it is moved to IA and > 90 days moves to glacier. so i cannot use the storage-class option here

Comment: Perhaps you should file your issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli  about the AWS CLI cp issues on different storage class.  Or raise a ticket in AWS forum.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this using bash and JQ, obviously python with boto3 or similar would be cleaner.

I don't know if you'd be better off adding a check to skip the GLACIER files, there's no magic way to apply encryption to them without unfreezing, then re-freezing them.

You'll want to run this on an ec2 instance local to the s3 bucket.

```
#!/bin/bash

bucketname="bucket-name"
aws s3 ls ${bucketname} --recursive | awk '{ print $NF }' > /tmp/filelist

for file in `cat /tmp/filelist`
do
        class=`aws s3api head-object --bucket ${bucketname} --key $file  | jq '.StorageClass' | sed 's/\"//g'`
        if [ "$class" = "null" ]
        then
                class="STANDARD"

        fi
        echo "aws s3 cp s3://${bucketname}/${file} s3://${bucketname}/${file} --sse  --storage-class ${class}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful.

Comment: When i recopy the IA objects for encryption will i be charged the retrieval fee?

Comment: It's worth saying in 2019 this isn't the way I'd do it, you can use S3 Batch with a manifest file and lambda to do this instead

Comment: You can run `jq -r '.StorageClass'` and ditch your sed process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the command line option --storage-class STANDARD_IA

Comment: I am using three different types of storage on the objects in the same bucket. object placed in the bucket is standard ,> 30 days it is moved to IA and > 90 days moves to glacier. so i cannot use the storage-class option here.

Answer (score 1):

Does your bucket have a lifecycle policy?  If so - it's actually behaving like it's supposed to - you are, in effect, creating a new object in the bucket, so the transition over to standard is, in fact, correct.

The option by Ewan Leith above is really the only way to do it - programmatically determine the current storage state, then override the storage of the 'new' item on save.

Hope this helps...